# how to write flash message from symfony2 service?

Tags: symfony

Could any of you symfony2 gurus enlighten me as to how I can write a flash message from a symfony2 service?

I thought I had what I needed when I injected the container as below, but apparently not, I get error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method appDevDebugProjectContainer::getRequest() in /var/www/cloudsign_beta/src/BizTV/CommonBundle/Helper/globalHelper.php on line 135
```

So apparently I can not access the request... If I have to pass that as well from the controller I will soon loose the point of a service, it being unable to do anything by itself =)

```
<?php
namespace BizTV\CommonBundle\Helper;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager as EntityManager;

use BizTV\CommonBundle\Entity\Log;

class globalHelper {    

    private $container;
    private $em;

    public function __construct(Container $container, EntityManager $em) {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function log($type,$message) {

        // currently $type can be 'success', 'fail' or 'error'.

        $currentUser = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $currentCompany = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getCompany();

        //if the $type is one that we want to write to the log then create log entity (we don't log failed attempts at operations, but we do log errors.
        if ($type == 'success') {
            $em = $this->em;
            $now = new \DateTime("now");

            $entity  = new Log();
            $entity->setCompany($currentCompany);
            $entity->setExecutor($currentUser);
            $entity->setTime($now);
            $entity->setEventType($type);
            $entity->setEventMessage($message);

            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();
        }

        //flash out the $message message text
        $container = $this->container;
        $session = $container->getRequest()->getSession()->setFlash($type, $message);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$session = $container->get('request')->getSession()->setFlash($type, $message);
```

But be careful as you may not be aware of whether `request` exists or not. A proper way of managing this would be by [restricting your service to the `request` scope](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html#setting-the-scope-in-the-definition).

Comment: Many thanks. I believe request will always exist as this will only be called after a form is validated by symfony.

Comment: wouldn't $container->get('session') be shorter?